# Entity Frame Work, One to Many paired with a Default One to One Relationship

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entities, a parent and a child.  The Parent Entity can have a list of children, but the newest child should always be the active child item.  To simplify and expediate the query, I want to be able to inner join the newest child, and not have to sort the list of children and get the newest one.  My entities are as follows:

```
public class Parent: TableHeaderParent
{
    [Column]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public Guid? ChildActiveId { get; set; }
    public virtual Child ChildActive { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child : TableHeaderChild
{
    [Column]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The one to many relationship works great, no issues.  I was able to configure the one to one relationship (ChildActive) using the fluent api and a foreign key (ChildActiveId).  However, I cannot have a foreign key in each table, as I am using SQL and I am unable to create the records without getting a circular reference error.

Is there away to accomplish creating this ChildActive navigation, without the ChildActiveId being a foreign key to my Child Entity?  I want to be able to use linq to query the database as follows:

```
var query = await DbContext.Parent.Include(x => x.ChildActive).ToListAsync();
```

instead of:

```
var query = await DbContext.Parent.Include(x => x.Children.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).Take(1)).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: As I know it is not possible.

Comment: But. with LINQKit. you can create extension which mimic such functionality. It will looks like `.Include(x => x.ChildActive())`

Comment: I am aware of LINQKit and actually am using it already in my project.  However, I don't need clean Linq syntax, I need a better query plan when accessing the SQL data.

Comment: So your Include is not performant?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, though honestly I don't recommend it because there is no assurance that the "ChildActive" actually must be in the Children collection.

The error you are getting if you have:

```
public Guid? ChildActiveId { get; set; }
public virtual Child ChildActive { get; set; }
```

The issue with this is that EF convention when looking for FK properties will be based on the type name (Child) not the property name. (ChildActive) You will likely have tried this:

```
public Guid? ChildActiveId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ChildActiveId")]
public virtual Child ChildActive { get; set; }
```

However this will likely result in a problem because ParentId on Child cannot serve as both the ends to a one-to-many and one-to-one relationship, so we need to tell EF that this is actually a many-to-one relationship acting as a one-to-one relationship. EF will look to try and enforce this, even though the underlying database cannot. This also needs to be a uni-directional reference. Using the modelBuilder reference:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasOne(x => x.ChildActive)
    .WithOne();
```

We cannot reference Child.Parent in this relationship because that reference is needed for the one-to-many.

The problem with this "primary child" relationship is that if a Parent has 3 children, IDs #1, #2, and #3, there is nothing stopping you from setting ChildActive to Child ID #4, which could be a child for a completely different Parent. The database would not complain as there is no way to enforce such a constraint.

An alternative approach would be to use an unmapped property on the Parent for the active child:

```
[NotMapped]
public Child? ActiveChild => Children.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

There are two caveats of this approach. Firstly, like any ignored property, ActiveChild cannot be used in any query expression that might be translated to SQL. EF is told to ignore this property so it has no way to translate this down to SQL. Secondly, this property should only be used when Children has been eager loaded or it might either return #null when there is supporting data, or trigger a lazy load of the Children collection. (Better of the two options, but a hidden performance penalty)  The advantage of this approach is that the ActiveChild is guaranteed / guarded as being associated with this parent and not breaking normalization relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  My primary concern is query performance, I use Linq to SQL.  I often times have several includes, with each include having to drill down to the newest child element.  This results in queries > 2-3 seconds, which is unreasonable and I know it can be better.  I've decided to use a nullable foreign key on the Parent entity.  Although this is also inconvenient, as I have to create the parent entity with a null FK, create the child entity, and then update the parent entity with the FK value.  However I believe the performance enhancement will be worth the extra roundtrip.